# ConstraintLayout usage restrictions

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I can see that Google actively promotes ConstraintLayout.
Is this means that it should be used in any case where this is possible?
I mean, if we have even some simple view with one or two child views, should we still use ConstraintLayout or this is not justifiable for simple views?
I mean from the performance perspective.
Are there any restrictions where usage is forbidden?

Answer (score 1):

Performance suffers when you have multiple nested views eg relative layout contains a linear layout which contains a scroll view etc etc

The nature of constraint layout is that you can achieve things possible only by nesting other views, in a single constraint layout without nesting.

As long as the simple layout does not contain nested views, there is no strong performance gain by using constraint layout.

Answer (score 0):

According to @Vardaan performances improvement is seen in the application which is also given in [android developer blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html) and using it eliminates deep nesting, but it’s way too hard to do complex layouts with it since we don't deal with simple layout now days [check this](http://myhexaville.com/2016/12/14/switch-android-contraintlayout/)